# Find a pivotal quantity

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood

I have a random sample from $X$, $X_1,...,X_n$, with X having probability density function
$f_X(x;\sigma^2)=\frac{x}{\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}},\;\; x>0, \sigma^2>0.$ We are also given that $E(X^m)=\sigma^m2^{m/2}\Gamma(1+\frac{m}{2})$ for $m=1,2,3,...$

I have shown that the $\hat{\sigma}_{\text{MLE}}^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}{2n}$, and I now want to show that $$\frac{\hat{\sigma}_{\text{MLE}}^2 n}{\sigma^2}$$

is a pivotal quantity. I know then that I have to find the distribution of this quantity, and that the distribution must be independent of $\sigma^2.$ I have done something similar when the parameter was given an exponential distribution, but I am unsure on how to proceed with this specific case. Any hints or help?

Comment: That is the [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution). The $X_i$ on the MLE for $\sigma^2$  are squared, so that $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i}^2}{2n}$. You can show that $X_i^2 \sim Exp(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2})$. From there, you can obtain the distribution for the pivotal quantity.

Comment: Typo by me to not square them!

Comment: I'm struggling to see the arguments why $X_i^2 \sim Exp(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2})$, could you please explain?

Comment: You need to use the [Jacobian Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar) to obtain the pdf for $X_i^2$. Let $Y = X^2$. The density function of $Y$ is $f_Y(y) = |\frac{dx}{dy}| f_X(x(y))$. Notice $x(y) = \sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Thanks, that made sense. I know that a sum of exponential random variables is Gamma distributed with $n$ as the first parameter, with the second parameter equal to the parameter from the exponential distributions. How would I find the distribution then of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}{2\sigma^2}$?

Comment: I basically multiply the quantity with $\beta$ in this case, so considering that $E(X)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ and $Var(X)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta^2}$, the new mean and variance is just both $\alpha$ and $\alpha$, making the $\beta$ parameter equal to 1? Thus getting the distribution $Gamma(n,1)$. Is this rigorous enough you think?

Comment: Update: I found the property from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009938/probability-density-function-of-scaled-gamma-random-variable that if $Y=aX$, then $f_Y(y)=f_{aX}(y)=\frac{f_X(y/a)}{a}.$ Using this property I got a clear pdf for a  $Gamma(n,1)$ distribution, however I'm struggling to see how the property always holds. Do you know of any resources for this @LucasPrates? And also, thank you very much for your help! My exam is up on wednesday, so I am very grateful.

Comment: If $Y$ has distribution $Exp(a)$, then $aY$ has distribution $Exp(1)$. The sum of $Exp(1)$ distributions has distribution $Gamma(n, 1)$. Try to relate this to your proposed pivotal quantity.